# How can I install drivers for Broadcom BCM4364 Wireless Network Adapter on Linux Mint 21.1?

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, broadcom

I've installed Mint 21.1 on a iMac 21.5" 2019. Everithing work fine excluding the Wi-FI. I Cannot use it. I've already tried to search on the web but i didn't find nothing for my network card excuding a solution that requrire a repo actually offline.
How can i install network card drivers?
The post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260088/how-can-i-activate-wifi-on-bcm4364-using-brcmfac-driver-firmware